# How to ignore spaces in url parameter with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to ignore spaces in a url parameters. Currently here is my line of script that gets the url parameter of a link.

```
var paramValue = href.split.('=')[1];
```

I want to modify it so it ignores any spaces found in the url parameter

Comment: What do you mean by ignore spaces? Can you show us an example of url and what also an example of what the final result might look like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the spaces.

```
var paramValue = href.split('=')[1].replace(/ /g, '');
```